# Disable Preview in Stacks in Snow Leopard (MAC OS X 10.6)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, dock, stacks

I have the following problem: in Snow Leopard, when you click on a stack or pile in the dock the system will display previews for the files in there. But for small text files, all you get in a preview is a few unreadable characters. I would much prefer to have their icon displayed (as in OS X 10.5), since I could then recognize them more easily (and it was much more beautiful also).

Any hints?

Comment: Have you considered using the pre-Leopard "List" view? Right-click the Stack and select *List*. You lose drag & drop, but you also lose the previews (a lose-lose situation :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Delete `/System/Library/QuickLook/Text.qlgenerator`.

You will lose all QuickLook functionality for text file types, both in "regular" QuickLook and Stacks.

If you only want to remove QuickLook from plain text file, edit `/System/Library/QuickLook/Text.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist` using Xcode and remove the following line:

```
<string>public.plain-text</string>
```

---

There appears to be a bug in the Stacks implementation: It ignores the property `QLThumbnailMinimumSize` that would be perfect to prevent tiny thumbnail creation. It works in Finder's regular views though if you enable icon previews.